# OTRS 3.2.14 - How to know how many mails have been sent on each queue?

Tags: email, report, sendmail, otrs

Is there any possibility to know how many emails have been sent through OTRS system ? When I try to search it on Google, response are about "How to schedule statistics by mail?" and this is not what I'm looking for.

In OTRS you can configure only one SMTP account to send mail (when you create a ticket or when you response/forward one ticket, you send a mail).

My mail provider is limiting send mail to 200 per hour, but I don't know which queue (which customer) is sending so much mail.

Is there any possibility to have a report under OTRS that shows me how many mails have been sent from each queue per hour ?

My Environment is : OTRS 3.2.14 Windows Server 2012 MSSQL 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All outgoing mail is recorded in the OTRS log. On Windows, this would be in `<OTRS>/var/log/otrs.log`. Just open this file and count the number of sent mails. It could well be that agent notifications are causing you hitting your limits.

Comment: OK I found on this log file data about sent mails, but only I can access to this log file. That's why I'm looking for a report that can be generated directly on OTRS. Don't you know any possibility to access this information through OTRS ?

Comment: No, I don't, because there is none :D 
The messages in the log file are recorded by the mail back end. And of course, if it'd be needed, you can record all outgoing emails in the database by creating a table for it and create a custom back end that also writes a record in the database table when sending mail.
I did that actually once, I implemented the mail backend using a database so you can do proper queueing and resending in case of failures; but it DOES require custom code. It's not configuration. It might be easier for you if you'd use a commercial email sender such as SendGrid.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help, I'll do something like that :)

Answer (score -1):

Everything is saved in database. 
You can use SQL query to determine that.
To get needed information you should join *ticket*, *article* and *queue* tables.

Comment: I think that, yes I can find a solution with a SQL query. But there is no possibility to have a report directly onto OTRS ? I have Database access, but if someone else need to know how many mails are send through this queue, must he ask me each time ?

Comment: Actually, outgoing mail might also be caused by notifications. Notifications are not recorded in any of these tables; just maybe in `ticket_history`. See my answer, IMO it'd be best to search in the OTRS log file.